# Fetching the EA Elements

Tags: enterprise-architect

We can fetch the element in the repository using the API `Repository.GetElementByID`. But the problem is using this API we can fetch only the specific element and not there child elements.So We have created the Package1 which contains Class A and the Part B which is child of Class A.So We have another Package2 which has the diagram. So I just got the instance of Class A from Package1 using the API `Repository.GetElementByID` and added to Package2 diagram.But only the Class A instance is fetched and not there child elements. So is there any API to fecth the element along with there child elements such that if the parent element is added to the diagram view we want there child elements also to be added to the diagram view using addin.

Answer (score 3):

Appearance of elements on a diagram must be handled individually. When you place an element on a diagram it will never contain its child elements. You need to iterate through the `Element.Elements` collection and create `DiagramObject` elements for each. And of course you need to calculate the geometry for parent and children as you need it.